# Trouble intercepting AJAX (XHR) requests from GreaseMonkey script

Tags: javascript, ajax, greasemonkey, xmlhttprequest

My userscript's task is fairly simple -to listen to XHR requests via an XHR bridge sort of functionality, manipulate the data received, and return it back. Everything happening transparently, of course.

I came across this reply [How can I intercept XMLHttpRequests from a Greasemonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629671/how-can-i-intercept-xmlhttprequests-from-a-greasemonkey-script/629782#629782) on SO -- which provides the following code-snippet:

```
(function(open) {  
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {  
        this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {  
            console.log(this.readyState);  
        }, false);  
        open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
    };  
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

The code works as expected when pushed via FireBug. It, however, doesn't do anything in a Greasemonkey script.

On further searches, I came across another reply: [how intercept xhr with greasemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688884/how-intercept-xhr-with-greasemonkey/688909#688909) -- which mentions that:

> Greasmonkey and Firefox 3.x doesn't currently support the "prototype"-property. Please see the following ticket for more information:
> http://greasemonkey.devjavu.com/ticket/164

I have two basic queries:

1. Does this apply to Fx v3.5.x as well? (Note: The ticket link on devjavu.com isn't accessible)
2. What does signature `(function(){})()` mean in Javascript. (Kindly bear, am not an expert in advanced JS).

Comment: Further to Tomasz's answer (to Q#2), here's a pointer for others:
http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Functional_Javascript#quickIDX5

Answer (score 0):

**function(){}** is anonymous function (lambda), adding **()** after simply executes it on the fly.
It's very handy to keep different (unique) scope for chunk of code.

```
(function(){
  var localVariable = 'temp';
})();
console.log(localVariable); // outputs undefined
```

Comment: Strictly speaking *lambda* means using a function as an argument in a call to another function, but +1 anyways :-)

Comment: Tomasz, Thanks for the clarification.
Any clue on the first question?