# how to capture request and response using selenium webdriver in c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am writing selenium test scripts using c#. I need to do this on IE11.

I am trying to do below:
1. Navigate to a page
2. When this page is loading, browser makes an API request
3. I want to capture this API request and then examine its content through code.

Is there a way to proxy request - response and retrieve its parameters within Selenium webdriver script?

I need to use C# for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: That's possible in Chrome, with some flags - look at the linked question, more specifically the answers with "Network.enable" (currently the 2nd by votes), and "--remote-debugging-port" (just a few votes).

Comment: @TodorMinakov sorry i should have mentioned in my question. i need solution on IE11.

Comment: This is where I would start off - intercepting the `XMLHttpRequest` requests, through javascript; look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335648/how-to-intercept-all-ajax-requests-made-by-different-js-libraries.