# Intercept Fetch API calls wit Axios

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios, fetch

We have a vanilla Javascript application that uses heavily `fetch` for AJAX requests.

As I need to intercept those requests to put some custom headers and other data, we found out that `axios` could be a good solution.

As I don't want to modify all the native `fetch` calls, is there a way to intercept those `fetch` requests with `axios` implicitly ?

Comment: Why can't you just use the `fetch` and modify the headers there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335648/how-to-intercept-all-ajax-requests-made-by-different-js-libraries/25335826

Comment: But also, there are some existing libraries that may help, like https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-intercept.