# How to get all XHR that a web page is making in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I am using `https://webdriver.io/` for automation.

Using this lib, I am opening a page  `https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted/` however I need to get the list `XHR` calls that page is making

```
class PricingPage extends Page {
 open() {
  return browser.url(
   "https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted/"
 );
 }
 // tried to do so however this is throwing error
 async captureNetworkRequest() {
  var capture_network_request = [];
  var capture_resource = performance.getEntriesByType("resource");
  for (var i = 0; i < capture_resource.length; i++) {
    if (capture_resource[i].initiatorType == "xmlhttprequest" || capture_resource[i].initiatorType == "script" || capture_resource[i].initiatorType == "img") {
        if (capture_resource[i].name.indexOf('https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted/') > -1) {
            capture_network_request.push(capture_resource[i].name)
        }
    }
}
return capture_network_request;
}}

module.exports = new PricingPage();
```

site.e2e.js

```
const PricingPage = require("../pageobjects/pricing.page");

describe("Crawler", () => {
 it("should get data", async () => {
 await PricingPage.open();
 await PricingPage.captureNetworkRequest()
 });});
```

However this is throwing the error

> performance.getEntriesByType is not a function

How can I get the `XHR` that this page is making?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library like [XHook](https://github.com/jpillora/xhook) that intercepts XHR requests. Pretty sure there are other libraries (even better than this one).

There's an existing Question already here in StackOverflow about this. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25335826/2678218) thread.