# equivalent of jQuery.active for pure Javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to check the active Ajax requests from a site which is not using jQuery so How can I write the equivalent of `jQuery.active`?

I want to check if the ajax requests finished after visiting the page.

i.e. I found `window.XMLHttpRequest` class but not sure how to use it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/3148506/2025923. It's just a variable defined on jQuery object.

Comment: @Tushar thanks but every solutions used jQuery.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but to clarify ... `window.XMLHttpRequest.DONE` is one of a family of read-only constants *(not quantities)*, each representing one of the possible states of an XHR instance - UNSENT:0; OPENED:1; HEADERS_RECEIVED:2; LOADING:3; DONE:4 . Not too sure where this is specified (W3C? IANA?) but it is common (IE, Chrome, Opera), probably universal.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 which of the following options shows the active XHR : UNSENT:0; OPENED:1; HEADERS_RECEIVED:2; LOADING:3; DONE:4 ?

Comment: As I say, they are constants.

Comment: And there's no such thing as "the active XHR". There may be none, one or more than one XHR at any given point in time and each of them will be in one of those states.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 updated the question. I wanna check if the ajax finishes or not after visit.

Comment: Assuming this to be a Greasemonkey scenario, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629671/how-can-i-intercept-xmlhttprequests-from-a-greasemonkey-script) may possibly provide part of the solution.

Comment: @MesutGÜNEŞ did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @JohnPollard unfortunately I still don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended using this. If window.ajax_active == 4 then I know the ajax request has completed. Seems to work for me so far.

```
window.ajax_active = 0;

(function(open) {
  return XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
    this.addEventListener('readystatechange', (function() {
     if (this.readyState == 1) {
        window.ajax_active += 1;
     } else if (this.readyState == 4){
        window.ajax_active -= 1;
     } 
    }), false);
    return open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
  };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

Comment: Not sure how to use it, when I call `window.ajax_active` it gives the assigned value

Comment: jQuery.active also gives the assigned value. What are you trying to do?

Comment: if we set `window.ajax_active = 0; ` it will return to 0 but `jQuery.active` returns the active ajax requests.

Comment: Can you show an example of jQuery.active returning active ajax requests?

Comment: Okay, yea that returns the number of active ajax requests, not the ajax requests themselves. Ill edit the answer above now.. I didnt test it so let me know if that works for you

Comment: Does that give you want you're looking for?

Comment: `} else if (this.readyState == 4){` line gives error. How could I use this check number acitve requests?