# How to check if any AJAX request is running on page via JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there any way to find any AJAX request is running on page (on `$(window).load` event) ?

I want to apply some event when all ajax request completed.

I have tried

`.ajaxStop(function(){
})`

but I want to put this block(`ajaxstop`) when AJAX request exist on page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `.ajaxStart()` to call a function when the first AJAX request starts. This can add the `.ajaxStop()` handler.

Comment: @Barmar: I need to apply ajaxstart only when if any ajax request are there, if there is no ajax request on page I don't want to execute this code.

Comment: I thought you needed to apply `ajaxStop` when there are ajax requests out there. `ajaxStart` will tell you when an AJAX request is started, so then you'll know that there are AJAX request.

Comment: @Barmar: yes but I don't want to apply `ajaxStart` if the page doesn't any ajax request.

Comment: Maybe **jQuery deferred _when_** would be useful [https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the beginning:

```
var ajax_running = false;
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  ajax_running = true;
});
```

Then you can later use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (ajax_running) {
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
      // do something
    })
    ajax_running = false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, which creates a function that will tell you how many active requests are pending.

```js
const activeAjaxRequests = (function(send) {
    var active_requests = 0;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(body) {
        active_requests++;
        this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
            if(this.readyState === 4) active_requests--;
        });
        send.call(this, body);
    };
    return ()=>active_requests;
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);

var active_requests = activeAjaxRequests();

console.log(`There are currently ${active_requests} active ajax requests.`);
```

Comment: it is always returning 0 request

Comment: @SunilKumar - that's because there are always zero requests when you run it...... try running it on your own page during an ajax request..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this functions is the first thing loaded to the browser:

```
(function(open) {

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {

        this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
            //Put your code here
        }, false);

        open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
    };

})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

Each time an ajax response is retrieve, the following listner functions is called, and is in there that you should put your code:

```
this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    //Put your code
}, false);
```

Note:
This code was extracted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335648/how-to-intercept-all-ajax-requests-made-by-different-js-libraries) which was used to intercept all ajax requests and from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629671/how-can-i-intercept-xmlhttprequests-from-a-greasemonkey-script/629782#629782) you don't need to pass the parameters on functions:

```
(function(open) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
            // put your code here!
        }, false);
        open.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

Comment: How I will check the Ajax request are running on page from your code, I mean what your code will return ?

Comment: Do I really need to pass the parameters i.e. method, url , async  etc ?

Comment: @SunilKumar I'm not understanding well your questions. My code will not return nothing. You just need to ensure that this code is loaded before any of your code that makes an ajax request. Then, for each response of an ajax request, the listener "readystatechange" will be called and in the listener function you can put wherever you want to do.

Comment: @SunilKumar I made some changes to my code so you can review it! I hopped as answer well your doubts

Comment: if there is no ajax request on page then which code block will execute ?

Comment: @SunilKumar None, this code will only be called if there is performed, ate least, one ajax request